# Как в Jasmine тестировать вызов функции в функции?

Tags: angular, юнит-тесты, jasmine

У меня в Angular проекте есть файл utils.ts, в котором:

```typescript
export const testFn = function(): void { };

export const testFn1 = function(): void {
  testFn();
};
```

Мне нужно протестировать функции в node.js (не в браузере)
Я пишу такие тесты:

```typescript
  describe('Тестирование функции testFn1', () => {

    let moduleObj: any = null;

    beforeEach(() => {
      moduleObj = { testFn, testFn1 };
    });

    it('должна выполниться без ошибок', () => {
      expect(moduleObj.testFn1).not.toThrow();
    });

    it('должна вызывать функцию testFn', () => {
      spyOn<any>(moduleObj, 'testFn');
      moduleObj.testFn1();
      expect(moduleObj.testFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

  });
```

Но второй тест ломается, `Error: Expected spy testFn to have been called`
Jasmine не видит вызова функции testFn, что я пишу не так?

Comment: Вызывать их надо разве не через utils? Ну т.е. `import * as utils from './utils'`, а потом `utils.testFn` и т.д.

Comment: @DiMithras сейчас посмотрю

Comment: @DiMithras тоже самое, впринципе, какая разница, нам же нужно наблюдать за вызовами функции в объекте. Мы назначаем функции - ссылки для свойства объекта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если коротко: то никак
Функция testFn1 может быть реализуема с какой-то другой функцией или без неё, а логика может остаться той же. Нужно смотреть на работу самой функции, что она принимает, возвращает, а не что происходит внутри неё, кто там что вызывает.